# Prophecy that people would be addicted to looking at screens?

Tags: catholicism, prophecy

I heard there was a private revelation / prophecy that people would be addicted to looking at screens. What is this prophecy?

Comment: Was George Orwell a mystic?

Comment: @PeterTurner He could've based it on something before him.

Comment: Idolatry has always involved visual stimulus. There are many prophecies about idolatry as such involving what is seen with the eyes pictorially, representatively and imagined in a visual way.

Comment: This will not be well received by this community because a majority of the users on this site stare at the screens to try and answer questions.